# Can I create two Recoll databases, each for different directories?

Tags: recoll

I have run Recoll which created a database for my data partition on my internal hard drive. The database is stored under my home partition in the same internal hard drive.

I now want to run Recoll to create a database for a dicrectory on my external hard drive, and store this new database on that external hard drive, because my internal hard drive doesn't have enough space to hold the new database. I was wondering how to do that in Recoll?

Note: my current Recoll was installed from software center of Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding answer from @Glutanimate - I will provide example of the solution based on creating different directories with recoll configuration for multiple indexes. Let's assume that we want to have "it books" and "health books" indexed separately.

1. First create directories for each index:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /path/to/the/index/.recoll_it
   $ mkdir -p /path/to/the/index/.recoll_health
   ```
2. Then launch `recoll` with option '-c' to indicate directory with configuration you would like to be loaded when `recoll` GUI will be launched, e.g.:

   ```
   $ recoll -c /path/to/the/index/.recoll_it
   ```
3. When `recoll` GUI is open, go to `Preferences` menu and select `index configuration` where you can indicate path to the directory you would like to have indexed with this configuration (in this example directory with collection of it books).
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 with the other configuration you might want to have.

Every time you want to use `recoll` with specific index you need to call `recoll` with option `-c` to indicate which index recoll have to load (as in step 2).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late but you will find extensive information on working with multiple indexes in Recoll's documentation and wiki:

- [Tutorial on creating multiple indexes](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/faqsandhowtos/MultipleIndexes.html)
- [excerpt from the documentation #1](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html#RCL.SEARCH.GUI.MULTIDB)
- [excerpt from the documentation #2](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/usermanual.html#RCL.INDEXING.CONFIG.MULTIPLE)

Comment: “Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.” [answer]

Comment: @Melebius Yes, sorry about the broken link. I was pretty new to the site 4.5 years ago. Unfortunately I simply don't have the time to go through all of my old answers, find the ones that aren't up to par, and update them. Thankfully izkeros did a great job of providing a comprehensive answer above.